# Stub a function inside a function without passing it as an argument

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon, stubbing, proxyquire

I have the following code:

```
const {compose} = require('./compose');


const complicatedFunction = async function (argA, argB) {
    const result = await getValue(argA)
    const value = await getValue2(argB)
    const composition = compose(result, value)
    validator(composition)
    return composition
```

I am calling the complicatedFunction to test the "validator" function. To test the validator function, I must stub the compose function to make it return whatever I want.

It would be easy to stub it and pass it as an argument, but it is not an option. How can stub compose to make it return any value? I know that proxyquire allows to mock dependencies but I don't understand how could I insert it in that situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`complicatedFunction.js`:

```js
const { compose } = require('./compose');

const complicatedFunction = (argA, argB) => {
  const result = 1;
  const value = 2;
  const composition = compose(result, value);
  return composition;
};

module.exports = complicatedFunction;
```

`compose.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  compose() {},
};
```

`complicatedFunction.test.js`:

```js
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const sinon = require('sinon');

describe('75761657', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const composeStub = sinon.stub().withArgs(1, 2).returns(100);
    const complicatedFunction = proxyquire('./complicatedFunction', {
      './compose': {
        compose: composeStub,
      },
    });
    const actual = complicatedFunction();
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 100);
  });
});
```